# Why React doesn't render a list on Android OS

Tags: android, reactjs, zooming

I have a React app that renders a list (using the `<li>` tag).

I render the list using values from props and mapping it like this:

```
{options.map((item, i) => (
  <li
    key={i}
    tabIndex='0'
  >
    {item.value}
  </li>
))}
```

It works correctly on desktop and iOS, but on Android OS I see whitelist without values. I see gaps, but I don't see values themselfs.
All values become visible when I zoom in on the page.

What could be the problem?

Comment: React native or Android browser?

Comment: @Mordechai React native, Google Chrome